# ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am encountering an issue while using Jupyter Notebook to train a model with the transformers library. The error message I'm getting is:

```
ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`: Please run `!pip install transformers[torch]` or `!pip install accelerate -U`
```

I have already tried the following steps:

1. Installed the latest version of accelerate using !pip install accelerate -U.
2. Installed the transformers library with PyTorch support using !pip install transformers[torch].
3. Restarted the Jupyter Notebook kernel after installing the libraries.
4. Ensured that the environmental variables are updated.

However, the error persists, and I'm unable to proceed with the training. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you see when you run `import accelerate; import transformers; print(transformers.__version__); print(accelerate.__version__)`?

Comment: I got this one 4.31.0 & 0.21.0

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, try:

```
!pip install -U accelerate
!pip install -U transformers
```

Then, restart the kernel and re-run the cell:

```
import os
os._exit(00)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a week ago and it looks like my colab notebook reset or something. I remember the issue is the latest version of transformer, the way I fixed it was installing an older version of transformer, I can't remember which version unfortunately it may not really matter. If I find the post where I found the fix I will let you know.

Comment: "!pip install accelerate>=0.20.3 transformers" worked for me, the post I used originally did, "!pip install transformers==4.17" then I restarted the runtime by going to "Runtime" at the top then "Restart Runtime".